# What does "innocked" mean?

Tags: serenity

In *Serenity* (2005), Malcolm scolds Kaylee for making difficulty in landing the
spaceship safely:

> Malcolm: If she crashes, you crashed her.

Malcolm then meets doctor:

> Malcolm: Doctor. Guess I need to get **innocked** before we hit planet-side.

What does "innocked" mean?

Comment: This is just a guess without checking any context, but given that he's asking a doctor about that, could it be that "innocked" = "inoculated"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a corruption of "inoculated" (against various diseases commonly found on the moon Lilac, presumably).

Seen later in [the screenplay](https://imsdb.com/scripts/Serenity.html);

> **Mal:** Honestly, doctor, I think we may really crash this time anyway.
>
> [Simon jabs **the inoculation needle** into Mal's arm.]

Interestingly, this is an actual word used in informal Scottish English, but it seems unlikely that Whedon would have known that when writing the script.